# Node msssql Local Server Login Failed

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my local microsoft sql server but the login fails. What would I set the username and password to if I use Windows Authentication to login into the server?

Error

> message: 'Login failed for user \'\'.', code: 'ELOGIN' },

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var dbConfig = {
    server:'DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database:'TEST',
};

sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from invoiceCharges', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to connect sql server using windows authentication.

this module "mssql" doesnt support this. use "mssql/msnodesqlv8" instead.

see this [link](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

```
var mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
var dbConfig = {   
    server: 'server',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    database: 'db', 
    port: '1433',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',        
        debug: {
            packet: false,
            payload: false,
            token: false,
            data: false
        },
        //encrypt: true
    }
};
```